# Why would h2 be a class in an h1 tag?

Tags: css, tags

Today, I ran across a tag, in the site of some acquaintances, that seems to have a structural flaw. But, I thought I would check whether my impression is on track before I mention it to them.

In what situations/purposes would using h2 as a class inside an h1 tag be a useful structure: `<h1 class="heading h2">` ?

Comment: You mean `<h1 class=h2>`?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I had copied the code and forgot to paste it. I will add it to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class names don't really mean anything as it relates to the structure of the page.

I suspect that your friend needed an h1 heading but liked the styling of the h2 class better.

You see this a lot with pre-developed frameworks (e.g. Bootstrap) where the base styling might not fit with what the developer is trying to go for. So rather than creating a new class or adding inline styles, they just opt for whatever is there (and maybe even leverage additional inline styles).

From a structure stand point, the tag is still communicating to search engines, accessibility tools, etc that it is an h1.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. That tag is on a site that uses a common shopping cart service. I have found it awkward enough to do custom coding on in that service, that I can see the temptation to cut corners.